# EndOfStreamException after executing zookeeper-shell.sh command

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm starting with Zookeeper and Kafka - after executing zookeeper-shell.sh commands I'm still getting EndOfStreamException. So far it doesn't cause broker failures (still getting valid responses) but I would like to resolve it before it starts. I operate on single cluster with 1 Zookeeper and 3 Kafka brokers. Commands I used so far are simplest possible:

- /bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
- /bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 get /brokers/ids/{id}

[Zookeeper command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig9zM.png)

[Zookeeper logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78hva.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're running a non-interactive shell command, then it exits successfully with code 0 and ends the session.